# Is there a way to automatically upload photos from an iPhone to Google Drive

Tags: iphone, ios, google-apps

With Dropbox, you have the option to upload all photos from your iPhone to Dropbox. Is there an equivalent for Google Drive? I.e. is there an app, that when I open it will upload all my photos from my iPhone to my Google Drive account?

I don't see a preference setting for this in the google drive app, and I have searched for 3rd party apps and nothing seems to do this.

Comment: Are you asking if the dropbox app integrates with google drive or looking for a recommendation for software that does? Please edit your tags and elaborate a bit if possible.

Comment: To improve this question you might want to talk about what you have found out already, e.g. "I don't see a preference setting for this" and "I have searched for 3rd party apps and nothing seems to do this"

Comment: e.g. means "for example" not "copy and paste" ;)

Comment: @dwightk I don't follow what is wrong with my question now. If you know of an answer, please feel free to answer it rather than attack the question

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is. I'm trying to help you make the question more likely to be answered. (I'm not one of the downvotes)

Answer (score 4):

You should use the app [**Photosync**](http://www.photosync-app.com/) which let you choose where to download your pictures, including Dropbox, Google+/Picasa, Box, 500Px and Google Drive (!) to answer your question.

Comment: Awesome app, thanks for pointing it out. Tried another free app to do that, forget about it: photosync provides so much more settings to upload your pics properly (target folder, format, & so on), and can also plug to so many services (googleDrive, Dropbox, flickr, 500px, SmugMug, & so on). I say buy it, it's well worth $3

Answer (score 1):

Use Google+! Switch on [auto back up](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509?hl=en), check settings to make sure it uploads over wifi only perhaps.

Also, the Google+ app offers the option to upload full-size photo files, which will use your Google Drive space allotment, or to upload unlimited "standard-sized" photo files. Standard size means they are resized to 2048 on the longest edge. This is a nice option if your photos are mostly snapshots or mostly just viewed on screen and never printed.

Comment: does this 'back up' to google photos as usual?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Google Drive has a built-in option for automatic photo backups.**

Go to Settings -> Photos and enable Auto-Backup. If you choose to upload in High Quality instead of Original, the uploaded photos won't count against your Google Drive storage limit.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: doesn't this back up to google photos instead of google drive?

Comment: @Pacerier There is a "Google Photos folder" option that stores Google Photos in a folder on Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this 'automatic uploader' too.

I downloaded the IFTTT app and added a recipe that checks if any new item is added to the camera row and, if so, store to google drive.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you're looking for the Google Photos app.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: google photos is terrible even with original quality selected because 1. app's UI is error prone failing POLA 2. no easy way to export bursts photos 3. no easy way to export more than 500 photos 4. no easy way to export more than 1 photo if edits were done 5. no easy way to disable accidental edits 6. it does random compression of screenshots 7. it has the fkin nerve to offer to delete your iPhone photos when it hasn't got them properly backed up. Now, Google Drive is supposed to be silver lining to google photos. Supposed..