# How do I sync my photo's from my iPhone to Google Drive?

Tags: iphone, photos, google-apps

I try to  find a way to sync my photo's on my iPhone to my Google Drive, it appears that this is not so easy, this is what I did allready:

1. In my photo app on my iPhone I select 4 photos > share > to google drive and select folder and that works.
2. I select 13 photos in my photo app > share and Google Drive is gone, I can't select it
3. upload photos in the Google Drive app and that works, it's a hassle because I need to delete the original photos from the photo app, that kinda sucks
4. then iCloud: I turned on sync with iCloud on my phone and on my mac I set it up to sync my iPhone photos with my mac to put those pictures in a specific location and what do I get when I open finder in that location? a whole bunch of F[2 digits] folders, how helpful is that?...
5. then I found this [topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124310/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-upload-photos-from-an-iphone-to-google-drive) and I tested photosync and I got excited I set up to sync the photos to a Google Drive folder in low quality because the original quality cost money.. and it works I tested it and deleted a photo in google drive and I synced again and the deleted photo came back in Google Drive. In my book that's not syncing.

I came from Android on my Android: I downloaded a drivesync app I set it up and BAM done, no problems.
Why is it so hard for IOS to sync photo's?

Does anyone here has a sync with iPhone photos to Google Drive working?
and I mean Google Drive not Google Photo's
on My mac and Windows laptop I sync the photo's and I have a renaming files and directory structure workflow, and I don't want to change that. So Google photo's is not an option.

Regards,
Ralph

Comment: I don't think Photosync actually syncs images, it's just a backup service.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, this is the solution closest to my needs.
On my and my wife's iPhone, I have set the photos to be stored in iCloud.

On my Mac, I open the Photos app and I have it set to load the iCloud Photos.

Now I can drag the photos into the correct folders of Google Drive which will be synchronized via drive sync.